# Let me fix thou number

Tags: java, object-oriented, strings, programming-challenge

Problem Statement:

> Write a program that cleans up user-entered phone numbers so that they
>   can be sent SMS messages.
>
> The rules are as follows:
>
> - If the phone number is less than 10 digits assume that it is bad    number
> - If the phone number is 10 digits assume that it is good
> - If the phone number is 11 digits and the first number is 1, trim the    1 and use the last 10 digits
> - If the phone number is 11 digits and the first number is not 1, then    it is a bad number
> - If the phone number is more than 11 digits assume that it is a bad    number
>
> We've provided tests, now make them pass.
>
> Hint: Only make one test pass at a time. Disable the others, then flip
>   each on in turn after you get the current failing one to pass.

Code:

```
public class PhoneNumber {
  private String number;

  public PhoneNumber(String number) {
    this.number = cleanNumber(number);
    setNumber();
  }

  public String getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  public String getAreaCode() {
    return number.substring(0, 3);
  }

  public String pretty() {
    return String.format(
        "(%s) %s-%s",
        getAreaCode(), number.substring(3, 6), number.substring(6));
  }

  private void setNumber() {
    if (hasInvalidInput(number)) {
      number = "0000000000";
    } else if (number.length() == 11) {
      number = number.substring(1);
    }
  }

  private boolean hasInvalidInput(String number) {
    return hasInvalidLength(number) || hasInvalidPrefix(number);
  }

  private boolean hasInvalidLength(String number) {
    return (number.length() < 10 || number.length() > 11);
  }

  private boolean hasInvalidPrefix(String number) {
    return number.length() == 11 && !number.startsWith("1");
  }

  private static final String cleanNumber(String number) {
    return number.replaceAll("[\\s\\.()-]", "");
  }
}
```

Test Suite:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class PhoneNumberTest {

    @Test
    public void cleansNumber() {
        final String expectedNumber = "1234567890";
        final String actualNumber = new PhoneNumber("(123) 456-7890").getNumber();

        assertEquals(
            expectedNumber, actualNumber
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void cleansNumberWithDots() {
        final String expectedNumber = "1234567890";
        final String actualNumber = new PhoneNumber("123.456.7890").getNumber();

        assertEquals(
            expectedNumber, actualNumber
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void validWhen11DigitsAndFirstIs1() {
        final String expectedNumber = "1234567890";
        final String actualNumber = new PhoneNumber("11234567890").getNumber();

        assertEquals(
            expectedNumber, actualNumber
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void invalidWhenOnly11Digits() {
        final String expectedNumber = "0000000000";
        final String actualNumber = new PhoneNumber("21234567890").getNumber();

        assertEquals(
            expectedNumber, actualNumber
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void invalidWhen9Digits() {
        final String expectedNumber = "0000000000";
        final String actualNumber = new PhoneNumber("123456789").getNumber();

        assertEquals(
            expectedNumber, actualNumber
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void areaCode() {
        final String expectedAreaCode = "123";
        final String actualAreaCode = new PhoneNumber("1234567890").getAreaCode();

        assertEquals(
            expectedAreaCode, actualAreaCode
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void prettyPrint() {
        final String expectedPrettyNumber = "(123) 456-7890";
        final String actualPrettyNumber = new PhoneNumber("1234567890").pretty();

        assertEquals(
            expectedPrettyNumber, actualPrettyNumber
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void prettyPrintWithFullUSPhoneNumber() {
        final String expectedPrettyNumber = "(123) 456-7890";
        final String actualPrettyNumber = new PhoneNumber("11234567890").pretty();

        assertEquals(
            expectedPrettyNumber, actualPrettyNumber
        );
    }

}
```

Again its not state of the art code, few points that's bugging me:

- AFAIK the computation should be avoided in the constructor but I didn't want to do the same computation again and again while getting the number so, I had to do the sin.
- The `getAreaCode` and `pretty` still uses and throws away strings don't know if its a good idea but by seeing that string isn't going to be too long I kind of traded of here.

Reference: [Exercism](http://exercism.io/exercises/java/phone-number/readme)

Comment: Your program does a lot more than the rules given in the problem statement describe.  In fact, the given rules don't seem to describe the stated task at all -- they're validity rules, not details of what it means to "clean up" a phone number.  Have you omitted part of the problem?

Comment: You might want to look at the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) which involves using work in constructors. You could build phone numbers using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: Umm… the question title doesn't make sense grammatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Make it immutable

In cases when you're forced to work in the constructor,
you might want to do *all* the work there.
On the other hand,
make the result of the calculations `final`,
and the object created immutable.

Your implementation was effectively immutable.
The value of `number` never change after construction time.
But this was not really guaranteed.
One could still accidentally add a statement to change `number`.
You can improve this, by making the `number` field `final`.

And if `number` is `final`,
then there's no point calculating area code either,
or the pretty format,
all these could be pre-calculated at construction time.

#### Pointless `static final`

The `static` and `final` modifiers don't make much sense together.
You can drop the `final` safely, as a `static` method cannot be overridden anyway.

#### More static methods

Many of the helper methods don't need access to the fields,
so could have been `static`.

#### The invalid number

The invalid number is not exactly trivial.
Instead of having it buried deep in the implementation,
it would be better to move it to a constant.

#### Suggested implementation

Putting the above suggestions together:

```
public class PhoneNumber {
    public static final String INVALID_NUMBER = "0000000000";

    private final String number;
    private final String areaCode;
    private final String prettyFormat;

    public PhoneNumber(String number) {
        this.number = cleanNumber(number);
        this.areaCode = this.number.substring(0, 3);
        this.prettyFormat = prettyFormat(this.number, areaCode);
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public String getAreaCode() {
        return areaCode;
    }

    public String pretty() {
        return prettyFormat;
    }

    private static String prettyFormat(String number, String areaCode) {
        return String.format("(%s) %s-%s", areaCode, number.substring(3, 6), number.substring(6));
    }

    private static boolean hasInvalidLength(String number) {
        return (number.length() < 10 || number.length() > 11);
    }

    private static String cleanNumber(String number) {
        number = number.replaceAll("[\\s\\.()-]", "");

        if (hasInvalidLength(number)) {
            return INVALID_NUMBER;
        }
        if (number.length() == 11) {
            if (number.charAt(0) != '1') {
                return INVALID_NUMBER;
            }
            return number.substring(1);
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thinking in OOP way I think that class PhoneNumber is doing too many things like its sanitizing the number `AND` its formatting it in proper, wdyt?

Comment: Sanitizing and formatting are closely related to the phone number, so it's perfectly fine to have these logic in this class

Comment: Sanitizing is fine, but formatting isn't. Formatting should be done by the "rendering" class.

Answer (score 2):

I would replace PhoneNumber constructor with the following:

```
public PhoneNumber(String number) {
    if (number.matches( Pattern.compile("(1\\d{10}|\\d{10})") )) {
        if (number.length == 11) {
            this.number = cleanNumber(number.substring(2, number.length));
        } else {
            this.number = cleanNumber(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Other comments:

- Setters (like `setNumber()`) should be simple Setters (you shouldn't be changing the number there, unless you change the method name). They should also take a parameter (the value you want to set).
- `pretty()` isn't a descriptive method name. It also looks like it's been formatted differently to the rest of your code for some reason. Copy & Paste job? Discuss the method name with the author of the tests - since the tests were provided and they reference the method name.
- There is absolutely no reason not to set internal variables appropriately in the Constructor. You're setting internal state ready for use, based on input provided. Calling `setNumber()` (especially with no argument) is more wrong than using the Constructor to establish internal state.
- The `pretty()` current implementation causes a bug if I call `new PhoneNumber("(123) 456-7890").getNumber()`

This problem looks like it's on a course that you're taking, and I would genuinely change the method names in `PhoneNumber` to provide `getNumber()` and `getFormattedNumber()` - and I'd delete `pretty()` completely. This would make the whole project fail to compile, and I'd hand the work in with JavaDoc comments explaining my choice of actions.

Then I'd probably get an F. :-)